# Is there a better way to do nothing in a if, else if, else sequence

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm doing an if, else if, else sequence within a foreach loop. In one of the states I don't want do do anything. Looks kind of weird and i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (item.Contains("some text"))
    {
        removeNext = true;
        myList.Add(item);
    }
    else if (item.ToUpper().Contains("TEXT IN UPPER") | item.Contains("some other text"))
    {
        // do nada
    }
    else if (removeNext)
        removeNext = false;
    else
        myList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: move it as parent condition with a not sign and your remaining if, else if, else within it

Comment: I do this lots of times. I don't mind how it looks.

Comment: You could use the 'continue' key word, so it'll give a hint that you're trying to avoid the else.

Comment: continue works for me, thanks :)

Comment: If you have `(BoolExpression1 | BoolExpression2)`, both expressions are evaluated before doing the OR operation.  If you have `(BoolExpression1 || BoolExpression2)`, you get _short circuit_ behavior, if `BoolExpression1` is `true`, then the OR is decided to be true without bothering to evaluate `BoolExpression2`.  The non-short-circuit version generates slightly more efficient code (I think), since it doesn't have to consider a the extra branch between the two Boolean expressions.  Of course, if the 2nd expression is heavy, then it's usually best to short circuit

Comment: You could start with a filtered collection: `foreach (var item in collection.Where(i => !(i.ToUpper().Contains("TEXT IN UPPER") || i.Contains("some other text")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse the condition and put the rest of the code inside.

Optionally, you could reverse the condition as well to get `if (!removeNext)`, making the code a bit shorted and arguably more readable, but also makes the assignment `removeNext = false` potentially useless, since it can be false already (but that's a negligible penalty).

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (item.Contains("some text"))
    {
        removeNext = true;
        myList.Add(item);
    }
    else if (!(item.ToUpper().Contains("TEXT IN UPPER") | item.Contains("some other text")))
    {
        if (!removeNext)
            myList.Add(item);
        removeNext = false;
    }
}
```

But personally, I think the 'flat',  unnested `if` that you have is way easier to read, and the `continue` command with a little line of comment, would make it nice and clear that that block intentionally does not have any code, and why.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write that logic is to keep track if the current item is being removed.  Then you can separate the logic that determines if the next item should be removed and the logic that determines if the current item is keep no matter what from the logic that actually decides if the current item is added to `myList`.  This way your condition clearly indicates it's purpose is to not remove the current item.

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    bool removeCurrent = removeNext;
    removeNext = false;
    if (item.Contains("some text"))
    {
        removeNext = true;
        removeCurrent = false;
    }
    else if (item.ToUpper().Contains("TEXT IN UPPER") | item.Contains("some other text"))
    {
        removeCurrent = false;
    }

    if (!removeCurrent)
        myList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another possibility, you can include all the logic in a `Where` statement and avoid the loop altogether. This takes advantage of the fact that an assignment returns the result of the assignment, which allows us to both set the `removeNext` variable and ensure that we include multiple `"some text"` items even if they're adjacent to each other in the collection.

Note that this idea is more just for fun rather than for real-world code, as it's hard to read and would be prone to errors if someone were to try to update it:

```
bool removeNext = false;

var myList = collection.Where(i =>
    !(i.ToUpper().Contains("TEXT IN UPPER") || i.Contains("some other text")) &&
    (!removeNext | (removeNext = i.Contains("some text"))));
```

---

**Explanation**

The condition before the `&&` strips out all the text we definitely don't care about. This was basically my comment under your original question (and by itself would be a good solution to pre-filter your results). The second part of the `&&` reads:

> "Select the item if `removeNext` is `false` OR if the result of the assignment `removeNext = i.Contains("some text")` is `true`"

The `|` is key here, because even if `removeNext` is `false`, we still want to do the assignment in the second part.

We don't use the `||` operator because it's a [short-circuiting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator), meaning that if the first part returns `true` it doesn't bother to evaluate the second part (normally we want this optimization), and the `removeNext` value would never change.